# How is the boy related to the girl?

Tags: logical-deduction, family

> Pointing to a boy a girl said "He is the son of the daughter of the father of my only uncle. "How is the boy related to the girl?"

A standard yet simple technique will be highly appreciated.

Options are:

1. Brother
2. Nephew
3. Uncle
4. Son-in-law
5. None of these.

Comment: When you post questions that are not of your own creation, _you need to say exactly where they come from_. If you are not willing to do that, your questions will keep getting closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boy is either the girl's brother or cousin. The girl's uncle's father is her grandfather. The daughter of the grandfather might be the girl's mother, or her aunt. The son of the girl's mother would be her brother (or half-brother, if they have different fathers), while the son of her aunt would be her cousin.

If we assume that the uncle is related by marriage and not by lineage (e.g., the mother's sister's husband), then the boy and girl may not be related at all.

Comment: Why are we assuming multiple daughters?

Comment: @RajorshiKoyal I'm not assuming, I'm simply stating the possibilities that cannot be ruled out - in the absence of more information, your grandfather's daughter might be your mother, or she might not be. Your aunt is the daughter of your grandfather, and so is your mother. There's nothing in the question that suggests your grandfather has exactly one daughter, so you could ask precisely the opposite question - why should we assume only one daughter? Without more information, we cannot determine the relationship definitively.